# Box collider with a specific shape

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've managed to create custom shapes in Unity by using Inventor. Problem is, that my Box-collider has a different shape than the shape of my actual object (which has curves and such). Is there a way to set the shape of my box-collider equal to the shape of my object? Thanks in advance.

[image: Box Collider Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or code, please?

Comment: I have provided a screenshot. Hope its useful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many different colliders to choose from. Perhaps a [MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider.html) is what you're looking for. Or, if you're doing a 2D game, a [Polygon Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html)

Comment: or consider using multiple simple colliders (Box + Sphere/circle) to mimic the shape you need

Comment: The StackOverFlow docs on Colliders: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/4405/collision

Comment: Thanks, I will take a closer look on the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

2 Options

1. Mesh colliders (easiest)
2. Multiple colliders form up to be nearest as your mesh (a lot better performance). In this case maybe box colliders.

Sample hierarchy should look like:

```
- Your Game Object // Rigidbody here if use.
 |- Mesh
 |- Colliders
 |- Colliders
 |- Colliders
```

Comment: Thanks. Did some research on the mesh-colliders and found the solution!